# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.auth(values.username, values.password).then')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm developing a ReactJS app.

I'm getting the following error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.auth(values.username, values.password).then')".

When the "`return new Promise`" is outside the "then" it works properly. Nonetheless, I want to return the promise after only the two first "then"s.

Sample of `loginActions.js`

```
export const auth = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  fetch('http://localhost/webservices/login', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  })
  .then(res => {
    if(res.ok) {
      console.log("Succeeded.", res);
      return res.json();
    } else {
      console.log("Failed.", res);
      return res.json();
    }
  })
  .then(json => {
    if (json.token) {
      auth_status.value = true;
      return auth_status.value;
    } else {
      auth_status.value = false;
      return auth_status.value;
    }
  })
  .then(function(res){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch({
        type: VERIFY_AUTH,
        payload: res
      });
      resolve();
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

Sample of `login.js`

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
        this.props.auth(values.username, values.password).then(() => {
          if (this.props.auth_status === true) {
            message.success("Welcome!", 3);
            this.setState({
              redirect: true
            });
          } else {
            message.error("The username and password combination is incorrect", 3);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: The function `auth()` that is passed as a prop does not return anything. To make the code work it should return a `Promise`.

Comment: Also what is `auth_status` referring to and where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action `auth` is not returning anything. The `return` statements in the asynchronous handlers do not return for the action itself.

You need to return a `Promise` in your `auth()` action that you resolve yourself in the third `then`:

```
export const auth = (username, password) => dispatch => {
    // instantly return a new promise that 
    // can be resolved/rejected in one of the handlers
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch('http://localhost/webservices/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();

            // your probably also want to reject here 
            // to handle the failing of the action
            reject();
        }).then(json => {
            if (json.token) {
                auth_status.value = true;
                return auth_status.value;
            } else {
                auth_status.value = false;
                return auth_status.value;
            }
        }).then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: VERIFY_AUTH,
                payload: res
            });

            // resolve the original promise here
            resolve();
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution + explanation!